# Latex code for power electronic inverters

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I need a code so as to get following circuit diagrams.[image: it is a voltage source inverter.]

[image: Z-source inverter]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: You could start by trying to get something with circuitikz. If you don't submit a partial example no one will do the job for you. This would be interesting for you http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/power-electronics-converter-inverter/

Answer (score 17):

Here is an example using `circuitikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{full Schottky diode/.append style={bipoles/length=.4cm}}
\tikzset{american voltages}
\tikzset{american inductors}
\tikzset{european resistors}
\begin{circuitikz}
    % TRANSISTORS
    \draw
        (0,2) node[nigfete] (t1) {}
        (0,0) node[nigfete] (t2) {}
        (2,2) node[nigfete] (t3) {}
        (2,0) node[nigfete] (t4) {};
    \draw
        (t1.S) to[short] (t2.D)
        (t3.S) to[short] (t4.D);
    % DIODES and transistor labels
    \foreach \num in {1,2,3,4} {
        \node[anchor=south] at (t\num.G) {$T_\num$};
        \draw (t\num.S)++(0,0.5) -- ++(0.3,0) to[sD*] ($(t\num.D)+(0.3,-0.5)$) -- ++(-0.3,0);
    }          
    % BATTERY connection
    \draw
        (t4.S) to[short,-*] (t2.S) to[short] ($(t2.S)+(-2,0)$)
        to[battery,l=$U$] ($(t1.D)+(-2,0)$) to[short,-*] (t1.D) to[short] (t3.D);
    % RL
    \draw
        (t1.S) to[short,*-] ($(t1.S)+(3,0)$) to[short] ($(t1.D)+(3,0)$) coordinate (p1)
        to[R,l_=$R$] ++(2,0) to[L,l_=$L$,i>^=$i_L$] ++(3,0) coordinate (p);
    \draw
        (t4.D) to[short,*-] ($(t4.D)+(1,0)$) to[short] ($(t4.S)+(1,0)$) coordinate (n1)
        to[short] ++(5,0) coordinate (n);
    % C
    \draw
        (p) to[C,l=$C$,i>^=$i_C$,v<=$U_C$] (n);
    % LOAD
    \draw
        (p) to[short,*-]($(p)+(2,0)$) to[R,l=$LOAD$,i>^=$i_o$] ($(n)+(2,0)$) to[short,-*] (n);
    % U_i
    \draw
        (p1) to[open,v^=$U_i$] (n1);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: tikz - Power Electronics]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{diode/.append style={bipoles/length=1cm}}
\tikzset{polar capacitor/.append style={bipoles/length=.7cm}}
\tikzset{inductor/.append style={bipoles/length=1cm}}
\tikzset{american voltages}
\tikzset{american inductors}
\tikzset{cute inductors}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \ctikzset{label/align = straight}
    % UPPER PART
    \draw
        (0,0) to[battery] (0,2) to[D]
        (2,2) coordinate (l11) to [L,l=$L_1$] ++(2,0) coordinate (l12);
    % LOWER PART
    \draw
        (0,0) to[short] 
        (2,0) coordinate (l21) to[L,l_=$L_2$] ++(2,0) coordinate (l22);
    % the crossing point of the capacitors
    \coordinate (c) at ($(l11)+(1,-1)$);
    % CAPACITORS
    \draw 
        (l22) to[short,*-] (c) to[pC,l=$C_1$,-*] (l11);
    \draw
        (l21) to[short,*-] (c) to[pC,l_=$C_2$,-*] (l12);
    % 3-PHASE INVERTER
    \foreach \n in {0,1,2} {
        \draw
            (l22) to[short] ++(\n+1,0) to[cspst] ++(0,.75) to[short] ++(0,.5) coordinate (p\n)
            to[cspst] ++(0,.75) to (l12);
        \draw ($(p\n)+(0,-\n*.25)$) to[short,*-o] ++(3.5-\n,0) coordinate (o\n);
    }
    % LABELS
    \node[anchor=north] at (o2) {\parbox{1.5cm}{\scriptsize To AC load or motor}};
    \node[anchor=north] at ($(c)+(0,2.5)$) {\scriptsize Z Source};
    \node[anchor=north] at ($(p1)+(0,2.5)+(0,-.25)$) {\scriptsize 3-Phase Inverter};
    \node[anchor=north west] at ($(0,0)+(0,2.5)+(0,1)$) {\parbox{2cm}{\scriptsize DC-Voltage Source}};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: tikz - Power Electronics 2]

Comment: Looks nice but I'd shorten the creation of the `t*` nodes: `\foreach \num in {1,2,3,4} { \node[anchor=south] at (t\num.G) {$T_\num$}; \draw (t\num.S)++(0,0.5) -- ++(0.3,0) to[sD*] ($(t\num.D)+(0.3,-0.5)$) -- ++(-0.3,0); }`.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Thanks, I have updated my answer.

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4472/misguided-answer-motivation

Comment: I am getting error with "\tikzset{american voltages} in these codes." My miktex is 2.7.  I also wish to share my codes for these inverters. Will you please tell me how to add codes as answers?